# Where is vim after pkg install?

Tags: vim, package-management, freebsd, raspberry-pi

Taking the first few shaking steps with FreeBSD. Started by installing `vim`I thought, but:

```
root@rpi:~ # pkg install vim
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (1 conflicting)
Cannot solve problem using SAT solver, trying another plan
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The most recent version of packages are already installed
root@rpi:~ # vim
vim: Command not found.
root@rpi:~ # echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
root@rpi:~ # find / -type f -name vim
root@rpi:~ # find / -type l -name vim
root@rpi:~ # echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
root@rpi:~ # rehash
root@rpi:~ # vim
vim: Command not found.
```

Even after `reboot` situation is the same:

```
root@rpi:~ # vim
vim: Command not found.
```

What am I missing? `pkg` can't really have done what it was supposed to, can it?

```
root@rpi:~ # pkg delete vim
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Package(s) not found!
```

`vim-lite` installs OK though.

```
root@rpi:~ # pkg info -l vim
pkg: No package(s) matching vim

root@rpi:~ # pkg which /usr/local/bin/vim
/usr/local/bin/vim was installed by package vim-lite-7.4.1832
```

`pkg upgrade` found nothing to upgrade, but `pkg autoremove` nuked all the `vim` dependencies:

```
root@rpi:~ # pkg autoremove
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Deinstallation has been requested for the following 70 packages:

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
    atk-2.18.0
    harfbuzz-1.2.3
    pango-1.38.0_1
    cairo-1.14.6,2
    cscope-15.8b
    ctags-5.8
    libXdamage-1.1.4_3
    libglapi-11.2.2
    gbm-11.2.2
    libEGL-11.2.2
    libGL-11.2.2
    damageproto-1.2.1
    xorg-fonts-truetype-7.7_1
    dejavu-2.35
    dri2proto-2.8
    encodings-1.0.4_3,1
    fontconfig-2.11.1_2,1
    libXft-2.3.2_1
    font-misc-meltho-1.0.3_3
    font-bh-ttf-1.0.3_3
    font-misc-ethiopic-1.0.3_3
    libXfixes-5.0.1_3
    fixesproto-5.0
    font-util-1.3.1
    mkfontscale-1.1.2
    mkfontdir-1.0.7
    freetype2-2.6.3
    libXpm-3.5.11_4
    python27-2.7.11_3
    glib-2.46.2
    llvm37-3.7.1_2
    glproto-1.4.17
    graphite2-1.3.8
    icu-55.1
    libX11-1.6.3,1
    libXt-1.1.5,1
    libXv-1.0.10_3,1
    libXvMC-1.0.9
    libXrender-0.9.9
    libXext-1.3.3_1,1
    libXxf86vm-1.1.4_1
    kbproto-1.0.7
    libSM-1.2.2_3,1
    libICE-1.0.9_1,1
    libxcb-1.11.1
    xcb-util-0.4.0_1,1
    xcb-util-renderutil-0.3.9_1
    libXau-1.0.8_3
    libXdmcp-1.1.2
    libdevq-0.0.2_1
    libdrm-2.4.66,1
    ruby-2.2.5,1
    lua52-5.2.4
    libffi-3.2.1
    libfontenc-1.1.3
    libiconv-1.14_9
    libpciaccess-0.13.4
    libpthread-stubs-0.3_6
    libxshmfence-1.2
    libyaml-0.1.6_2
    pciids-20160522
    pixman-0.34.0
    png-1.6.21
    readline-6.3.8
    renderproto-0.11.1
    tcl86-8.6.5_1
    videoproto-2.3.2
    xextproto-7.3.0
    xf86vidmodeproto-2.3.1
    xproto-7.0.28

The operation will free 402 MiB.

Proceed with deinstalling packages? [y/N]: y
[...]
```

After installing vim-lite the `find` from before finds the `vim` binary:

```
root@rpi:~ # find / -type f -name vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
```

So `pkg` really did not install the package.

Comment: It finds 1 conflict, but the second path it tries says `0 conflicting` should that not be OK?

Comment: `vim` is already installed. You can confirm which packages are installed with `pkg info`. The binary is at `/usr/local/bin/vim`. I don't know why your shell cannot locate it.

Comment: `pkg info -l vim` will show the installed files from package `vim`. Did you run `pkg upgrade`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, that is weird.

On the RPi, `pkg install vim` goes through the process of downloading 46 packages, but only installs 17 of them. Consequently `vim-7.4.1832.txz` is never actually installed.

Clearly, this is a bug with one or more of the packages on the ARM platform.

Hopefully, you can live with `vim-lite` for now.

Comment: should I report this somewhere? to a package maintainer?

Comment: See the [bug reporting page](https://www.freebsd.org/support.html) on the website.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using the default FreeBSD shell: `csh` ?

This is not `bash`.
You need to update your shell current command dictionary with a simple `rehash` before trying to access just installed commands.

Comment: `csh` is right, `rehash` did not help though. Added more info above.